# How to use decorator @st.cache with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, caching, sqlalchemy, streamlit

I have a problem using sqlalchemy with streamlit cache. The following function (`st_get_shop_ids`) works fine without the `@st.cache` decorator. However, when the decorator is added, it runs forever (literally, as if it is in an endless loop and laptop starts overheating wildly).

```py
@st.cache
def st_get_shop_ids() -> pd.Series:
    print("st_select_ids")
    shop_ids = ping_shop_id()
    return shop_ids

def ping_shop_id() -> pd.DataFrame:
    session = SessionLocal()
    query = session.query(FacebookAd.shop_id)

    df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, session.bind)

    return df["shop_id"]
```

Python doesn't even do the printing (first line in function) as if it blocks completely. I have also tried adding `@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)`, but to no avail. I used to have the code from the help function `ping_shop_id` inside the `st_get_shop_ids` then I got the `Streamlit cannot hash an object of type <class ‘sqlalchemy.orm` error.
The way I understand caching, Streamlit only caches input and output of decorated functions (which are in my case of type string and `pandas.DataFrame`, neither of which should be problematic).

Answer (score 0):

Use `hash_funcs` to tell Streamlit how to hash the object of class `sqlalchemy.orm.PATH.TO.CLASS`.

```py
@st.cache(hash_funcs={sqlalchemy.orm.PATH.TO.CLASS: id}, allow_output_mutation=True)
def st_get_shop_ids() -> pd.Series:
    print("st_select_ids")
    shop_ids = ping_shop_id()
    return shop_ids

def ping_shop_id() -> pd.DataFrame:
    session = SessionLocal()
    query = session.query(FacebookAd.shop_id)

    df = pd.read_sql(query.statement, session.bind)

    return df["shop_id"]
```

Comment: I didn't know how to find this path because error stopped displaying (the code simply ran forever without error) and there used to be more sqlalchemy objects streamlit couldn't cache. However, I managed to solve it using st.experminetal_memo decorator instead of st.cache. Thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Write it as an answer then! :)